# Plot Frequency Sweep In Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want a sinus with linear increasing frequency in the range `[f_start : f_stop]` over time.

However, when creating the appropriate signal in Python the last period has approximately twice the frequency expected, `2*f_stop`.

Why?

Here some minimal Python code which illustrates the problem:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Delta_t = 1     # Unit: Seconds
samples = 1000

total_time = samples*Delta_t
t = numpy.linspace(0,total_time,num=samples)

f_start = 1.0/total_time             # slow frequency (Period T = 1/f_start = 1000 samples)
f_stop = 100.0/total_time           # high frequency (Period T = 1/f_stop = 10 samples)
f_sweep = numpy.linspace(f_start,f_stop,num=samples) # Sweep from slow to high frequency


# Create Sinusoids
sinus_f_start = numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*f_start*t)
sinus_f_stop = numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*f_stop*t)
sinus_f_sweep = numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*f_sweep*t)


# Plot all sinusoids
fig = plt.figure()

fig.add_subplot(311)
plt.plot(t,sinus_f_start)# Perfect! 1000 Samples per period.

fig.add_subplot(312)
plt.plot(t,sinus_f_stop) # Perfect! 10 Samples per period.

fig.add_subplot(313)
plt.plot(t,sinus_f_sweep)# Fail! Last period has 5 samples.

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 sin(w*t)  => the angular velocity is   d(w*t)/dt =   w

sin(w*t*t) => the angular velocity is d(w*t*t)/dt = 2*w*t
```

hence the perceived doubling in the maximum frequency

Comment: Thank you! In ordetr to realize a linear sweep the frequency is w = 2*PI*(f_start+k/2*t) with k the slope parameter.

Comment: @Jack If we say the argument of the sine function is an angle \theta and we specify the angular velocity as a function of time (whatever time dependency), we will have to INTEGRATE the angular velocity with respect to time, i.e., \theta = \theta_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t}\omega(\tau) d\tau.  The expression you give for a linear variation of the angular velocity is ok. Ciao